# /var/www/html/admin

Tags: 16.04

I want to ask, I'm making a voip project using asterisk. Nah accidentally the admin directory in / var / www / html was delete, how to solve it yes sir? I've been trying to find tau but nil.
Please respond sir.
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to recover deleted files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files)

Answer (score 2):

> accidentally the admin directory in `/var/www/html` was deleted

The easiest method would be

```
mkdir /var/www/html/admin
```

If though you also want to restore what was inside the directory  `/var/www/html/admin/` you will need to rely on a backup you previously made.